# System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am writing a code that will create a object customer and display it

Class1.cs is the model I am using:

```
using System;                       
using System.Collections.Generic;                       
using System.Linq;                      
using System.Web;                       

namespace WebApplication4.Models                        
{                       
    public class Class1                     
    {                       
        public class Customer                       
        {                       
            public int Id { set; get; }                     
            public string CustomerCode { set; get; }                        
            public double Amount { set; get; }                      


        }                       

    }                       
}
```

under Default1Controller I have :

```
using System;           
using System.Collections.Generic;           
using System.Linq;          
using System.Web;           
using System.Web.Mvc;           


using WebApplication4.Models ;          


namespace WebApplication4.Models            
{           
    public class Default1Controller : Controller            
    {           
        //          
        // GET: /Default1/          
        public ActionResult Index()         

        {           
            Class1.Customer ob = new Class1.Customer();         

            ob.Id = 1001;           
            ob.CustomerCode = "C001";           
            ob.Amount = 900.23;         
            return View(ob);            
        }           
    }       
}
```

I right clicked ActionResult and added a view with the following code:

```
@model WebApplication4.Models.Class1

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

    <html>


    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

        <body>

            <div> 
                 The customer id is: <% = | Model.Id %>  < br/>
                 The customer Code  is: <% = | Model.CustomerCode  %>  < br/>
                 The customer Amount is: <% = | Model.Id %>  < br/>

            </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run the code , i am getting :

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WebApplication4.Models.Class1+Customer', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication4.Models.Class1'.

---

ok, I took out the nestled class under Class1.cs,

so now it only says public class Customer.

and I also changed namespace WebApplication4.Models

to namespace WebApplication4.Controller under DefaultController1.cs,

but when I go under Index.cshtml, it says

The Type or namespace Class1 does not exist in the namespace WebApplication4.Models

Answer (score 4):

Your controller is instantiating an object of type `Class1.Customer()` passed to the razor View, whereas your View has been told to expect a model of type `Class1`.

You have a nested class - I'm not sure if this is intentional?

If it is, change the view to:

```
@model WebApplication4.Models.Class1.Customer
```

**Edit**
I've compiled and run this:

**Model** (/Models/Customer.cs)

```
namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string CustomerCode { set; get; }
        public double Amount { set; get; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**  (/Controllers/Default1Controller.cs)

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication4.Models;

namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class Default1Controller : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var ob = new Customer
            {
                Id = 1001, 
                CustomerCode = "C001", 
                Amount = 900.23
            };

            return View(ob);
        }
    }
}
```

**View**  (`/Views/Default1/Index.cshtml`).
Note razor uses `@Model...` not `<%= Model....%>` like web forms.

```
@model WebApplication4.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<html>
<head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        The customer id is: @Model.Id  < br/>
        The customer Code  is: @Model.CustomerCode  < br/>
        The customer Amount is: @Model.Amount < br/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Produces the following page at `MyApp/Default1/Index`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        The customer id is: 1001  < br/>
        The customer Code  is: C001  < br/>
        The customer Amount is: 900.23 < br/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user2439070 I've compiled and run the above. Just note the `@` syntax of razor vs the `<%=` syntax of webforms.

Comment: ok i have made these changes, but it is still not recognizing Customer as a model at the line @model WebApplication4.Models.Customer under the view